# Link specific numbers of pixels

Tags: javascript, html, pixel

I was wondering is there any way to make some html element like div, image map or any other linkable elemente to fill only specific amount of pixels.

Example. If I click within document I will get coordinates of my click (it could be 100x100) and than if I want 23 pixels to be filled and linked somewhere around that area. Is it possible?

Comment: depends what you want these for, but if you want to create a custom shape you can later access you might want to consider using an SVG or inserting a CANVAS element.

Comment: Just give them dimensions? Could you add a concrete example of what you're trying, including HTML markup?

Comment: I don't have any html markup. But my idea is to make somekind of image map. But problem is that I cannot use background-color on image map and on canvas is hard to link shapes.

I need somehow to generate some shape with specific number of pixels (23px,57... doesn't matter, everytime is different). This area of pixels must be linked to some site.

E.G. it is difficult to make shape that consists of 23pixels exactly. if you understand me